# Do I really add this line for each class in my model using ninject and NHibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, inversion-of-control, ninject

I am using NHibernate and ninject in ASP.Net MVC, [using this page as a guide](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/07/using-nhibernate-in-asp-net-mvc/).  One thing I think is weird is that, in this code (half way down the page)

```
public class RepositoryModule : NinjectModule
{
     public override void Load()
     {
        const string connectionString = @"Server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=trucktracker; Uid=root; Pwd='your_own_password';";

        NHibernateHelper helper = new NHibernateHelper(connectionString);
        Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToConstant(helper.SessionFactory).InSingletonScope();

        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<ISession>().ToProvider(new SessionProvider()).InRequestScope();
        Bind<IIntKeyedRepository<Truck>>().To<Repository<Truck>>().InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

I think it's odd that you need to have this line per model:

```
Bind<IIntKeyedRepository<Truck>>().To<Repository<Truck>>().InRequestScope();
```

If I have 100 different tables (and thus models) do I really need to add this line in for every class that I have?  Is there not a better way where I can just declare this once and use inheritance to pass in the Type in my controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Open Generics support:-

```
Bind(typeof(IIntKeyedRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>)).InRequestScope();
```